# Where can I get images from the android checkbox

Tags: android, image, file

where can I get the images from this checkbox?

[image]

I downloaded Android Studio but I didn't find these icons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

these are part of SDK. You can't access these. If you wanna dig deep, look for the "RadioButton" class and see how they are drawn.Press Double Shift and SEARCH for "RadioButton".Of course, you can set the states of RadioButton programmatically or in XML.